# Bootstrap Carousel - Blurred Static Text Box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using the Bootstrap carousel, and I would like to add text that stays statically when you resize the window, and for mobile devices/tablets. I tried adding a H1 element, but it did not work correctly (moves about when resizing).

I have attached an image of how I would like it to look, with a blurred background so you can see the text as some images are of phones, and routers etc.
[how I would like it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpuiI.jpg)

This is the code currently: (not sure if you need to see the CSS, or the java)

Please could someone assist me, pretty new to web development.

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 70vh;
  min-height: 350px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-caption {
  width: 28em;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 65%;
  bottom: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>
  <div id="carouselIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="5"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="6"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('phone.jpeg')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4"></h2>
          <p class="lead"></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('telecommunications.jpeg')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4"></h2>
          <p class="lead"></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('fibre.jpeg')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4"></h2>
          <p class="lead"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('support.jpeg')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4"></h2>
          <p class="lead"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('wire.jpeg')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4"></h2>
          <p class="lead"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('5g.jpeg')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4"></h2>
          <p class="lead"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('internet.jpeg')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4"></h2>
          <p class="lead"></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Please provide CSS, add a post include example or link to the site showing current state.

Comment: Have added the CSS for the element, the current state is shown in the screenshot (just without the text boxes and background square)

Comment: @JamesSkinner I made a snippet out of this but still couldn't get the output as you posted in the image.

Comment: @Manjuboyz thanks, and yeah the images are stored locally and need to import the bootstrap which I will do now